# How can I see my code in my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi genius programmers how can I see my code in my website I'm currently making a web page tutorial where in you can see codes but the code I inputted is always executing can anyone help me about this?
Thank's a bunch.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <body>

    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: keystroke `f12`

Comment: right click anywhere within the page and click on `Inspect Element`. May be different per browser

Comment: what i mean how to bypass code in my website like in w3school site. you can see codes.

Comment: [pre tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to convert all your `<` to `&lt;` and all your `>` to `&gt;` and wrap everything in `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags. Like so:

```html
<pre>
  &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
    &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
    &lt;title&gt;Page Title&lt;/title&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;

    &lt;h1&gt;This is a Heading&lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;

    &lt;/body&gt;
    &lt;/html&gt;
</pre>
```

Comment: That's what I want fvcking looking for, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MOJOJO if this is the answer mark this as the best answer and give an up vote.

Comment: how can i align it to left? it always on the center.

Comment: @MOJOJO Nothing you've shown us would center anything. Post a [mcve] demonstrating what you're seeing. Note that using `<pre>` tags preserves any white space in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

The old-school solution (deprecated since HTML3.2 and removed/discouraged in HTML5) that still works is to wrap everything inside an [`<xmp></xmp>` (example) tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp).
The idea is that it can hold any string *except* the string representing the start of the xmp-closing tag: `</xmp`
Besides it being deprecated since forever there are browser-inconsistencies and other nuisances (like copying text from an xmp in firefox removes line-endings, or how much spaces a tab-character represents and the like).

The correct way is to **just escape the `&` and `<` character** *(in this order)* !
No need to escape the `>`: that's just myth since we already took out the open-tag-character `<` (and I thoroughly checked current and historical specs regarding this)!!

Obviously escaping the `&` characters prior to escaping the `<` character is because `<` becomes `&#60;` and then becomes `&38;#60;` (displayed as `&#60;` instead of the intended `<`) if we did not start by escaping the `&` characters first!

You can then wrap the result inside any tag, like `<pre>`, `<code>`, or ...

That leaves you with new-lines:
You either replace them with `<br>` or set the appropriate css-styling rules to control white-spacing (if they were not already set as default like for a `<pre>`-tag).

**Live example:**

```html
<textarea style="width:99%;height:150px;"></textarea>
<button onclick="
  var txt=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
  txt.value=txt.value.replace(/\u0026/g, '\u0026#38;').replace(/\u003c/g, '\u0026#60;');
">HTML-Escape (&#38;) and (&#60;)</button>
```

Fine print:
Maximum cross-browser (read ancient) compatibility is obtained by using decimal escapes since hexadecimal escapes were later added and implemented. Named entity escapes (like `&amp`) had similar problems (also in embedded javascript) because of the serious status these characters have/had in pre-parsing the HTML!

Theoretically there is a bigger rule-set regarding when `&` must absolutely be replaced and when it's not required (yes theoretically you don't need to escape all `&` characters, mainly just the ones that would render a valid escape and this is an ever-growing list since the living standard).
Thus the simplest and fastest way is to just replace them all! No need for special algorithms utilizing lookup-lists etc..

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this.

```js
function show_html(){
  var val = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value
  val = val.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
  val = '<pre>'+val+'</pre>';
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = val
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="html" onchange="javascript:show_html()"></textarea>

<p id="result">sdf</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `textContent` and the `innerText` can be used to convert HTML code to plain string. You can use something like the following:

```html
<textarea style="width:99%;height:150px;"></textarea>
<button onclick="
  var htmlText= document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
  
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  result.innerText = htmlText;"
  >Convert HTML to plain text</button>

<div id="result" style="width:99%;height:150px;"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hit f12 for the developer tools or press Ctrl+U for the source code